# Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element'. API can only be initiated by a user gesture

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen, galleria

I translate via "Google translate", sorry in advance if everything is not correct.

In "**smartphone resolution**" and on all browsers (IE10, Firefox, Safari) the "**fullscreen**" mode works very well, but not on "**Google Chrome smartphone**".

When an image of the gallery passes in full screen, the gallery disappears ...
Here is the error message sent by the console (**F12**)

> Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture

For example, try [https://galleria.io/preview/classic](https://galleria.io/preview/classic/)/ in Google Chrome on smartphone, when double-clicking to zoom an image of the gallery in "full screen", the gallery disappears :-(

**Is there a way to temporarily fix or a prevu update to fix this problem?**

Thank you.

**--- EDIT ---**

Here is  the code of or seems to come up the error (via online console 257)
https://github.com/worseisbetter/galleria/blob/master/dist/galleria.js

Comment: In short, you can't. The API is designed such that the user has to explicitly choose to enable fullscreen mode, and it seems like the code is executed too far from the actual double click event (so that the browser thinks it's not caused by user interaction). You cannot programmatically trigger it--how would you feel if you load a webpage and it immediately enters fullscreen mode without your consent?

Comment: Can you include the actual code which makes this request, so that we can see if it is possible for you to trigger this event inside the (should be trusted) double-click event?

Comment: View what the console says (F12) it seems that the error is here
http://hpics.li/5a8da8d

Here is  the code of or seems to come up the error (via online console 257)
https://github.com/worseisbetter/galleria/blob/master/dist/galleria.js